# Iterate over intervals of a list

Tags: python, list, intervals

Maybe I'm too spoiled with the usual awesomeness of Python, but is there a more natural way to iterate over intervals of a list?

Instead of:

```
L = [12, 15, 29, 100, 239]

for i in range(len(L)-1):
    print L[i], L[i+1]
```

> 12 15
>   15 29
>   29 100
>   100 239

is there somthing like this:

```
for i, j in intervals(L): 
   print i, j
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for i, j in zip(L, L[1:]): 
   print i, j
```

Comment: Very cool! Is there also a more "explicit" keyword (maybe in itertools or collections)?

Comment: @Basj there's a `pairwise` recipe in the itertools module